# how to addClass to section while scrolling, loop issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am building a website who has multiple sections, and I want to **give an active state to the section every time the section is in the viewport**. My HTML structure looks like that:

```
<header></header>
<section id="intro"></section>
<section id="schools"></section>
<section id="quotes"></section>
<section id="projects"></section>
```

and so on...

In CSS, my sections are defined by the VH units. In order to work with defined vertical breakpoints, I calculated them and came out with a sequence that I am using as an array in Js.

```
// Cache the Window object
var windowScroll, $h, pos;
$window = $(window);

// Cache the height of the window for future reference
// as section height = 100vh, 2nd section = h * 2, 3rd = h * 3, and so on
$h = window.innerHeight;

// pos[0] is the end of the header,
// pos[1] is the end of the 1st section
pos = [$h * 1, $h * 2.1, $h * 3.2, $h * 4.7];

// Cache the sections in an array
sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
```

It's working if I am writing this:

```
if ((!$(sections[0]).hasClass('active')) && (windowScroll <= pos[0]) && (windowScroll <= pos[1])) {
    console.log("Scroll is contained between " + pos[0] + " and " + pos[1]);                        
    $(sections[0]).addClass('active'); //
}
```

But I'd like to avoid writing it for each sections. If I am trying with a *for* or an *each* loop, it is adding the class to every sections at once, without targetting the one in the viewport.

```
// This is not working
$(sections).each(function(i) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        if ((windowScroll <= pos[i]) && (windowScroll <= pos[i+1])) {
                console.log("Scroll is contained between " + pos[i] + " and " + pos[i+1]);
                $('section').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fct57p1/12/

Comment: mind throwing what you currently have into a fiddle? Makes our lives easier :-)

Comment: Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fct57p1/4/ - I don't understand tho, the same code is running locally without any bug (I've got a on_window_scroll not defined) :(

Comment: still looking at your code, but the `undefined` is from `scroll_timeout = setTimeout("on_window_scroll()", scroll_trigger_time);` -- change "on_window_scroll()" to on_window_scroll (no quotes or parens)

Comment: Oh, right. I updated it with some comments, just to clarify

Comment: Change the _"onDomReady"_ to "Wrap in <head>"  in your fiddle and you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry, the update: https://jsfiddle.net/0fct57p1/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xtpqwjur/

Code:

```
// Cache the Window object
var windowScroll, $h, pos;
$window = $(window);

// Cache the height of the window for future reference
// as section height = 100vh, 2nd section = h * 2, 3rd = h * 3, and so on
$h = window.innerHeight;

// pos[0] is the end of the header,
// pos[1] is the end of the 1st section
pos = [$h * 1, $h * 2.1, $h * 3.2, $h * 4.7, $h * 6.2];

// Cache the sections in an array
sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");

// Avoid loop on scroll function
var scroll_timeout, scroll_trigger_time, userScrolled; // Cache variables
var userScrolled = false; // The scroll is false by default
var scroll_trigger_time = 100; // Trigger after x ms of scroll

function on_window_scroll() {
    if (userScrolled) {
        userScrolled = false;
        $('section.active').removeClass('active');        
        $(sections).each(function (i, value) {
          if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') && (windowScroll >= pos[i] && windowScroll <= pos[i+1]) ) {
            console.log('scroll between ' + pos[i] + ' and ' + pos[i+1]);
            $('section.active').removeClass('active');
            $(sections[i]).addClass('active');
          }
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    userScrolled = true;
    if(scroll_timeout !== null) clearTimeout(scroll_timeout); // Clear the scroll cache at if time is out
    scroll_timeout = setTimeout(on_window_scroll, scroll_trigger_time); // Trigger a function within the scroll
    windowScroll = Math.floor(window.pageYOffset); // Listen to the scroll position

});
```

Main issue was your comparison operator -- you were doing

```
(windowScroll <= pos[i]) && (windowScroll <= pos[i+1])
```

which says, "if the scroll position is LESS than (section) AND LESS than (section + 1).

I changed to:

```
(windowScroll >= pos[i] && windowScroll <= pos[i+1]
```

which says, "If the scroll position is equal or greater than (section), AND less than or equal to (section + 1).

you could change the upper bound (`<=pos[i+1]`) to just be less than ( instead of less-than-or-equal-to) to prevent overlapping conditions.

Comment: I spent something like 3 days on that... Yeah I changed it, but after a while you don't see where is the issue anymore. Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: Haha, happens to all of us. Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes. Glad to help. :)